# Play audio with PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyqt5, media-player

If in `playAudioFile` is performed, icon has changed but `play()` method dosen't work. Every time the condition is false.

This code works in some files, but I can't see a rule. Format files and file's long doesn't matter. I tried with .wav, .mp3 and .mp4 for a try.

In windows player every files work.

```python
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QStackedWidget, QMainWindow, QStyle
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent

class Term2(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi('screen2.ui', self)

        # create player
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.choose_music()
        self.btn_play.clicked.connect(self.playAudioFile)

    # play audio
    def choose_music(self):
        filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pc.wav')
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath)
        content = QMediaContent(url)
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        print(filepath)

    def playAudioFile(self):
        if self.player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.player.pause()
            self.btn_play.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay)
            )
        else:
            self.player.play()
            self.btn_play.setIcon(
                self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause)
            )

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QStackedWidget()
t2 = Term2()
widget.setWindowTitle('Project)
widget.setFixedWidth(700)
widget.setFixedHeight(400)
widget.addWidget(t2)
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I created button in Qt Designer and import in `loadUi('screen2.ui', self)`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also consider that the file extension doesn't always correctly indicate the actual media format.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with a proper wav, ogg or mp3 file. Does the problem always very for the same files? Do you have any of those files that you could temporarily upload somewhere to test? Have you checked the console output to see any debug message? What OS are you on? Note that while QMediaPlayer is slightly old, it doesn't play content on its own, and it is an interface with the OS multimedia codecs. If you're on Windows, you might need the K-Lite codec pack.

Comment: @musicamante console doesn't put error on console screen, program is work. I tried play these sounds which doesn't work in QMediaPlayer in pygame as suggested Gamaray and it works. Here is exemplary sound which does not work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b4RX9FveKSQambo40UzfVd7cR6oRbkXR/view?usp=sharing
I use win 10.

Comment: I can partially reproduce the issue on Linux, as the audio actually starts after about 9 seconds from its beginning (can you check it?). In fact, while the file is stored as a "wav" file, it is actually an AAC one. While, technically, it *is* possible to have compressed formats in a WAV container, I wouldn't consider it as "very standard". It is possible that the inability to play it correctly *is* indeed a bug, but that's difficult to find out. Unfortunately, the QtMultimedia has suffered various issues (especially with "non-standard" combinations of containers and codecs) and since Qt has ->

Comment: -> decided to block further updates to the open source version, it will never be fixed. What you can do depends on your needs. Consider that in Qt6 the QtMultimedia module has been completely rewritten, so it is possible that it works as expected (or, at least, you could file a bug report that *may* be fixed). pygame can indeed be less "picky" but you have to be careful in its usage, ensure that it's not blocking for the Qt event loop and see if it actually provides a reliable interface. In any case, after converting the file (without reencoding) with a proper container works properly.

Comment: @musicamante I changed PyQt5 to PyQt6 and it's work so you were right. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an audio player from a different library, that one appears quite old. I would recommend looking into playsound or the pygame audio mixer.
Playsound works like this:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound(path_to_audio_file)
```

It is quite limited in abilities, but is simple, reliable, and works with all mp3 and wav formats. Here is a tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/play-sound-in-python/

If you want something a little more advanced I would try out pygames audio mixer, you can play stuff, control volumes, timings and more. At its most basic:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(path_to_audio_file)
mixer.music.play()
```

The best format for the mixer is wav, but others would probably work.
A tutorial for this one:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-playing-audio-file-in-pygame/

Comment: @Gamaray while QMediaPlayer has certainly some issues (at least in Qt5), the fact that it's "old" is probably pointless in this case, especially considering that 99% of today's formats were already available when the last current release was published, and, most importantly, it doesn't directly play media files internally, but it's an interface with the OS multimedia backend.